# Hide the last added div in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a p-dialog where I am choosing some values and onclick of Apply all the selected values are shown on the main component template. Each value which is added will be separated by a border line(I kept border line inside a div). I have to remove the border line for last added item.

How can we add that logic? can anybody help me fixing this?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you are using a loop in your template, you could just use index to know when the last item was rendered and add a css class. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:last-child` to select the last div and hide it.

```
div *:last-child {
    //css-rule here
}
```

A working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/41kcfbpq/

Based on Kris comment:

> This is sort of a brute force approach and will require some changes
>   depending on the context. OP needs to provide more detail in that
>   regard.

Comment: Without context it is unknown if OP has other elements within the DIV that are meant to be visible. And this will hide every type of element inside all divs throughout the entire application.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: Make sense, he can add an additional class to it and then use this rule.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that this is sort of a brute force approach and will require some changes depending on the context. OP needs to provide more detail in that regard. But I would mention it in the answer as we don't know what OP knows and doesn't know. They might not be aware that this will apply the CSS rule to any `:last-child` element at any point within the context of a `div`.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: Updated the comment, feel free to edit it. Thanks